# Firebaseanimatedlist: How can I display username / date only once for subsequent list items (chat)?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, flutter, stream-builder

I am receiving data via FirebaseAnimatedList + Firebase Realtime Database within a live chat. It is a group chat with many users. Consider a similar code like this one, where Firebaseanimatedlist automatically listens for new items which are then displayed.

Currently, every list item has an avatar, author, text (I also added datetime).

**I want to achieve 2 things (similar to e.g. WhatsApp):** 
 1. Only show date once as a 'heading/toast' within the chat for messages of that date and the time in every message  (e.g. Februar 8th: message 1 (time), message 2 (time), ...February 9th message 1 (time), message 2 (time), ...
 2. I want that when there are subsequent messages
    of the same author, that the author and his avatar are only displayed once above the first message and the margin of these messages is smaller. WhatsApp uses both features.

```
new FirebaseAnimatedList(
          query: reference,
          sort: (a, b) => b.key.compareTo(a.key),
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          reverse: true,
          itemBuilder: (_, DataSnapshot snapshot, Animation<double> animation) {
              return new ChatMessage(
                snapshot: snapshot,
                animation: animation
              );
            },
          ),
```

where ChatMessage looks like this

```
class ChatMessage extends StatelessWidget {
  ChatMessage({this.snapshot, this.animation});
  final DataSnapshot snapshot;
  final Animation animation;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SizeTransition(
      sizeFactor: new CurvedAnimation(
          parent: animation, curve: Curves.easeOut),
      axisAlignment: 0.0,
      child: new Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
        child: new Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
              child: new CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: new NetworkImage(snapshot.value['senderPhotoUrl'])),
            ),
            new Expanded(
              child: new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Text(
                      snapshot.value['senderName'],
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead),
                  new Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                    child: snapshot.value['imageUrl'] != null ?
                    new Image.network(
                      snapshot.value['imageUrl'],
                      width: 250.0,
                    ) :
                    new Text(snapshot.value['text']),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is known as a grouping operation, and you implement it by keeping the "last seen date" in a variable and then only rendering a group header when the date of the new chat item is now the same as the last seen date (and updating the latter of course). I don't know how to do this in Flutter with an ItemBuilder though.

Comment: Sound doable - but I ve no clue how to implement it within an automatic Streambuilder / Firebaseanimated list logic which is based on index. Maybe something like comparing index and index+1? Any approach ;-)?

Comment: Nope, I would've answered if I knew. I hope somebody else has done someting similar and can answer.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I am also looking for similar - mainly a date grouping separator. The answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55199281/how-to-access-query-from-itembuilder has allowed me to use the items stored in the map to insert separators when the date changes but I am unable to create a 'header' date for the first message in the chat. I can't find a way of determining the total number of items in the list when using FirebaseAnimatedList.