# How to access query from itemBuilder?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-animation

I am make random chat app use FirestoreAnimatedList (FirebaseAnimatedList for Firestore).

I want show user avatar only one time if same user send many message so not have same avatar show many time.

My solution is use index for check if last message send by same user.

So I need check like :

```
if (snapshot[index - 1][‘user’] == user) {
  return true;
}
```

But my `snapshot` is `DocumentSnapshot` so cannot call `[index - 1]`.

Maybe I must get list from `query`?
How to access so can call `index` on list and `query` like this?

Thanks!

Here example:

```
body: FirestoreAnimatedList(
        query: firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
        itemBuilder: (
          BuildContext context,
          DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
          Animation<double> animation,
          int index,
        ) {
          return FadeTransition(
            opacity: animation,
            child: MessageItem(
              index: index,
              document: snapshot,
              onTap: _removeMessage,
            ),
          );
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just store the users in a `Map`.

In your widget's `class`, you will have to create a variable to hold the map:

```
final Map<int, dynamic> users = {};
```

Then, you can populate the map in the `itemBuilder` callback:

```
itemBuilder: (
          BuildContext context,
          DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
          Animation<double> animation,
          int index,
        ) {
          users[index] = snapshot['user']; // added line
          return FadeTransition(
            opacity: animation,
            child: MessageItem(
              index: index,
              document: snapshot,
              onTap: _removeMessage,
            ),
          );
        },
```

Now, you can do what you wanted:

```
if (users[index - 1] == user) {
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I was think about this but is not efficient? This create another user map from `DocumentSnapshot`. But app is already fetch all `DocumentSnapshot` in `query`. So duplicate

Comment: @FlutterFirebase It is a very simple `Map`. You will not notice this in neither memory nor other performance. You should not use this premade plugin if you wish to have customizability. The only thing you should worry about when using this `Map` is when to clean it up, however, I cannot tell you how to do it because I do not know how your application works.

Comment: Thanks! So no way get original list from `query`? Maybe better I use listviewbuilder